# Color cross table values based on condition in spotfire

Tags: colors, visualization, spotfire

I have a cross table in spotfire which has % values in the visualization. I wanted to color values in this visualization based on 'absolute value (1) > value from the cross table'  and this color change in this particular visualization should reflect another visualization which is a cross table too.

is this possible to do in spotfire ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about "this color change in this particular visualization should reflect another visualization which is a cross table too" but for your coloring scheme you can

1. Right Click on the cross-table
2. Select Colors
3. Click the Add drop down, and select your % column
4. Clock Add Rule
5. Change the Rule Type to Greater Than

You can apply gradients as well if you'd like to rank your percentage. i.e. %100 is bright red and 0% is white, with the scale gradually shifting for values in between

Comment: i meant that if i add a rule to first cross table, it should reflect another cross table as well. @scsimon